# Textbox is not accessible to js. Need a help to resolve

Tags: asp.net, performance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8ZXY.png)
js: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2qCa.png)
".value" is inaccesible in js to access content of textbox

only .innertext and .innerhtml is available in the suggestion not .value property.
Have to display textbox value in the alert.

Comment: Use the developer console and look at how the control is named. Then use that name to reach the control content

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="This is fun text in label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Get Label and Text box" 
        OnClientClick="mytest();return false"                
        />

    <script>
        function mytest() {

            var tbox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').value

            alert("text in textbox1 = " + tbox)

            var tlabel = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerText



            alert("text in Label1 = " + tlabel)

        }
    </script>
```

result:

[image]

so, for a text box, you use .value

so, for a label, you use .innerText, or .innerHtml.

For jQuery, then this:

```
            tbox2 = $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID  %>')

            alert(tbox2.val())

            // set value into text box
            tbox2.val('this is the new value of text box')

            alert(tbox2.val())
```